# Grub and ubuntu HDMI No Signal

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, hdmi

I have dualboot windows and Ubuntu. Whenever I power on the pc the grub come up, and it does! but the monitor shows hdmi no signal, until it boots into windows by default. After booted into windows I restart it and finally shows me the grub, and I can choose ubuntu. Idk if it's related but The hdmi gives no signal also after suspend, I do am able to wake him back, but the monitor says no signal.

I have an nvidia rtx 2060. I thought it was a problem of not recognizing my monitor, but now that it does (I disabled secure boot), it's still the same.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu (which should give you the HDMI signal), and then edit /etc/defaults/grub

Change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line to this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='root=/dev/sda2 video=LVDS-1:d crashkernel=128M@16M resume=/dev/sda4 udev splash rw'
```

Change the sda2 and sda4 depending on your setup

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure tho on how should I rewrite sd2 since i haven't partitioned the disk and ubuntu did for me. the two partiotions on my disk are dev/sda1 labeled as EFI System, dev/sda2 labeled as Linux filesystem